# Restricted Use License (RUL) limitations on objects, APIs and standard Salesforce features

Tags: licenses

I tried to find any SF documentation or articles that explain about the limitations on objects, APIs and standard Salesforce features when a user is assigned RUL. SF documentation gives an overview of this license type but not in-depth details such as limitation on objects, APIs, standard salesforce features. It does not have any details on the difference in pricing based on number of objects, features that an user would use. It would be great if someone share some documentation, blogs or articles that has in-depth details that includes the above details. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restricted Use Licenses are a contractual construct, and are not enforced at a platform level. Essentially they are a standard license (like Sales Cloud or Public Sector Solutions) that you've agreed to only use specific aspects of. If you're using these, it's up to you to ensure that you're not breaching the limitations that you've signed up for as part of acquiring the licenses. This could include only providing access to certain objects to users assigned that license or not using specific features like Business Rules Engine for example.

In terms of cost, because this is a contractual agreement that depends on a factors like volume and how restrictive the license is, there's no way to provide you with any information on pricing.

If you're considering using an RUL, then this should be discussed directly with your Salesforce Account Executive who can work with you on how you might be able to define an RUL and what this might cost.